# Creating a restful method that takes a posted xml and creates an entity

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

How can I take an xml that looks like:

```
<request>
  <User>
    <name>name value</name>
    <age>13</age>
  </User>
</request>
```

And then I can deserialize this into a User object that has matching properties.

```
public class User {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  // getter and setters
}
```

Is there anything simple I can do or do I have to parse the xml manually for this?

I'm using spring mvc, and this is in a method where the xml will be posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller method should take an argument of type `User`, which is annotated with [`@RequestBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html). Then you need to configure a [`MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.html) with an appropriate marshaller/unmarshaller. An example, straight from the reference guide:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <util:list id="beanList">
        <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
      </util:list>
    </property
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" 
       class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" 
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller"/>
```

Take a look at ["Supported method argument types"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) and ["Mapping the request body with the @RequestBody annotation"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) in the reference guide for more details.

Comment: I need a more concret example :)  Will the above configuration setup handle all my models/entities?

Comment: Yes. That's it. It varies if you choose a different marshalling library, of course. Spring ships with support for several. See [known implementations of Marshaller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller.html). Castor and XStream will handle any POJO you throw at it. I'm not sure about Jibx and XmlBeans. JAXB requires at least the @XmlRootElement on any class that's to be processed.

Comment: Jersey uses JAXB out of the box.

Comment: Can we use annotation to do the setup?

Comment: @AllanRuin: If you mean using Spring annotations vs. XML config, then yes, of course. The two are entirely interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Digest. 
It will bind your XML elements to your POJOs.
Here is a complete tutorial : 
http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/10/23/digester.html